# Creating a JSON RESTful API to load contents of a CSV file and display

Tags: python, json, django, rest, csv

I have been given an assignment to load the contents of a CSV file and display the content in a mobile application using Python and Django. I am relatively new to Python and Django. I know of the Django REST framework. But how do I go about with it? Please do let me know

EDIT:

This is the code I have so far. I have been trying to upload the CSV file and trying to parse the file after that.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import csv
import codecs
# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from items.models import UploadFileForm


def handle_files(f):
  reader = csv.DictReader(open(f))
  for row in reader:
    print row


def home(request):

  if request.method == "POST":
     form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        handle_files(request.FILES['csv_file'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/')
     else:
        print form.errors
        print request.FILES
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/workflow/upload')
  else:
     form = UploadFileForm()
     return render(request, 'template.html', {'formset': form})
```

template.html

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

  <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

items/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from items import views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
#url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$', views.home , name='home'),
  ]
```

customer-data/items/urls.py

```
  from django.conf.urls import include, url
  from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', include('items.urls')),
```

]

Comment: please share your state, what have you done? where is your problem?

Comment: I have edited with whatever I have do so far :)

Comment: I am stuck at the part where my uploaded file is not recognized and I would like to know how to parse the file once it gets recognized

Comment: please use name="csv_file" in your python code here: handle_files(request.FILES['file'])

Comment: @chfw Thanks. But I am still unable to read the CSV file and display the contents on a webpage

Comment: @Keshava, please reference the example in [django-excel](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for your needs